# hadoop connection with c#

Tags: c#, ubuntu, hadoop, connection

Can someone direct me in a right direction, im installed hadoop 2.7.3 stand alone cluster with hive how the connecting to my database should be done using c#?

```
7825 ResourceManager
8309 RunJar
7414 DataNode
8166 NodeManager
7641 SecondaryNameNode
7228 NameNode
9372 Jps
8526 Main
```

Answer (score 0):

You connect to Hive using ODBC Driver. Read [Using the Microsoft Hive ODBC Driver in a .NET client](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn749834.aspx).

Comment: "System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection class with the Hive ODBC driver to query Hive tables in the HDInsight cluster." and I'm running hadoop cluster on my local machine would it still be the same?

Comment: Yes, Afaik the driver is unrelated to HDInsight service. There is an Apache ODBC Driver too, but only for Linux, see  https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveODBC